# How to download a website in PHP - I have a small problem. (or major?)

Tags: php, html, http

I am learning PHP, and I'm trying to make an application that has a relationship with an external website.
I need to download it.
So I got this code:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

Which should return me the HTML contents of a website.
it works fine for most websites, but for a particular one - http://www.fxp.co.il - it shows crap.
What is the problem ? What can I do to fix it ?
Thank you !
[image]

Comment: Why did you obfuscate the URL?

Comment: The content is being sent gzip'd?

Comment: I obfuscate the URL for privacy reasons. duh. -the content of google are also gzipped - and still they show up well...

Comment: @Quantic Programming: What do you mean by 'duh'? If you don't want you URL to be public don't post it on a public (CC licensed) website :P

Comment: cURL: http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/ <- used that, returned the same gibberish...

Comment: @Quantic Is it exactly the same gibberish, or different gibberish? (this is actually a serious question)

Comment: another thing - some pages within the websites, it loads, but some not. http://www.fxp.co.il/forumdisplay.php?f=712 is A OK, but f=716 - nope. I'm using WebMatrix (microsoft)

Comment: @Quantic Programming: Do not make any assumptions in debugging, just check everything. See my answer. It's gzip'ed, and I have no problem to gzdecode it. Everything works as intended, the remote server is just ignoring that you have not send any `accept-encoding` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should actually inspect the response headers as they tell you about the encoding of the data returned `file_get_contents`.

For example, if it's gzip encoded, you need to uncompress it.

Normally you won't notice that because `file_get_contents()` sends a request in a way that the server knows that it does not support compression.

However some servers just do not care and send you compressed responses anyway:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.fxp.co.il/';

$buffer = file_get_contents($url);

echo $url, '<hr>', '<pre>', implode("\n", $http_response_header), '</pre>';

$bare = gzdecode($buffer);

echo '<hr>', htmlspecialchars(substr($bare, 0, 256));
```

Output:

```
http://www.fxp.co.il/
------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2011 19:19:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: bb_lastvisit=1314607056; expires=Tue, 28-Aug-2012 19:12:44 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bb_lastactivity=0; expires=Tue, 28-Aug-2012 19:12:44 GMT; path=/
X-Accel-Expires: 600
Cache-control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 14170
Expires: Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT
X-Header: Boost Citrus 1.9
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" lang="he"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset
```

Take care!

Comment: thats wierd- it was because I didnt have the function itself in my code. I copy paste it from php.net... now it works. PHP's wierd...

Comment: Hmm, I suggest you enable error reporting when you debug: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);`.

Comment: @knittl: Thanks for taking care, really appreciated!

Comment: @knittle: I do if I spot them :)